# Can we submit binary and executable related questions?

Tags: discussion

There is an interesting concept (in my eyes) of [fat binaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_binary), and I have an idea of a challenge. Besides the fact that it may not be too feasible in this context, I feel like if anyone can do it, it would be this community. The problem arises from the fact that it may fall into more of a *post*-programming puzzle.

My idea is a challenge to create the smallest fat binary with the points based on how many systems it works on, divided by how large the size of the file is.

Basically, is the reverse of [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260/should-executable-binaries-be-considered-a-reasonable-solution-for-code-golf) allowed.

Comment: The other problem arises in defining what counts as a different system for the purpose of scoring.

Comment: How many systems does everyone have available to test on? If I say it works on something (preferably very obsolete/esoteric), can it be *easily* determined if I'm right?

Comment: Those are very good points. I don't currently have answers for those. Peter: I think I'd have to go with different OS (by name not version), but that just means someone has to find a Linux distribution with the most branches and they win. Geobits: The best answer I have is VMWare, but that has its limits, of course. I'll think more on this, but I think those issues will make this unfeasible.