# Should graphical-output challenges accept straight up image files by default?

Tags: discussion, rules, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output

I've often seen some questions tagged [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) and [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) that have some answer being image files, and they are often disagreements in the comments.

#### examples:

[`Swiss flag (PNG)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137171/98630) [`Swiss flag (GIF)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136969/98630) [`Iceland flag`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85444/98630) [`Carpet an airport`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117693/98630) [`Minecraft tool`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225453/98630) [`Super Mario`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/39926/98630) [`RGB colour grid`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183338/98630)

Here's what comment section looks like (taken from the first example [`Swiss flag (PNG)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137171/98630)):
[image: Comment section screenshot]

> #### Note:
>
> This question is not realy about SVG; while they are some disagreements, it seems like it's more accepted than bitmap files. This is probably due to the fact that it isn't binary, but XML, which is closer to code than a binary bitmap image is. So you can talk about it but this is not the main focus of the question.

I gathered the arguments for and against it from the comments and some of my research:

| For | Against |
| --- | --- |
| [kolmogorov-complexity](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity)['s description](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/kolmogorov-complexity/info) mentions a complex string, which shortest representation might be to print it literally. If a **literal string** is considered the "worst case solution" to a string based code-golf, a **literal image** file could be considered a "worst case solution" to an image based code-golf. - [Sunday](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61199), in [`Carpet an airport`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117693/98630) | **PNG isn't a programming language**, this **isn't "drawing" anything**, it's just the pre-drawn output file handed out on a platter. That makes a profoundly **un-interesting** submission. - [Caleb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1256), in [`Swiss flag (PNG)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137171/98630) |
| [Answering in **non-programming languages** is **allowed**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10426/98630) on [Do submissions have to be answered with a programming language?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10421/98630) | It could be **compared** to a **compiled code** (binary executable) which [users seems to agree](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/260/98630) on the fact that they **shouldn't be valid answers** |
| It's kind of **interesting** that a generic commonly used image format like PNG can come close in size to the solutions using **code tailor-made** to this particular image - [Anonymous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64380), in [`Swiss flag (PNG)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/137171/98630) | This could give an **unfair** advantage, especially on pictures with a **small colo(u)r palette**. While I haven't seen any submission that wins, most of them are pretty **close** to first place |

Comment: I'll write up a full answer later if someone doesn't beat me to it, but IMO, yes, this is fine. These are files that, when run through an "interpreter" (e.g. an image rending software), produces the appropriate output. I don't see how this isn't allowed. That said, I agree that it's not very interesting

Comment: Yea I agree for the most part but it can be interesting, especially if it is manually crafted. Unlike in code where you can make a procedure specific to the image, there you have to deal with general-purpose compression algorithm. Choosing the right palette/mode/features is part of the challenge (though compressors does that very well already and it's hard to do better by hands). And as for scripts, an explanation of the tools and tricks used always make the answer that much more interesting.

Comment: The link on your second *against* point is very old, and the community has shifted a lot. Standalone executable machine code programs (and even functions) are definitely allowed, and there is quite some activity in machine code golf - check out [the search result for answers containing "machine code"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa%20machine%20code).

Comment: Also, handcrafting smaller zip files is (at least sometimes) an interesting area on its own (which is what Bubblegum users often do), and handcrafting images is IMO not so different. I don't see any unfair advantages with this (when a specific image format can be small, code generating it can be equally small), and code golf is mainly an [intra-language competition](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13945/78410) after all.

Comment: As for the "unfair advantage" part, languages no longer (technically) compete against each other, so any concerns about it being unfair aren't relevant anymore.

Comment: These answers could easily be posted languages like `///` which almost always just output the program's contents untouched, and then they'd be allowed. So banning them would seem very inconsistent (as well as, IMO, stupid)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The thing is that not all image formats are created equal.  Some are just straightforward uncompressed streams of pixels, and there is basically nothing you can do to golf those down.  However if your format uses a compression algorithm, for example PNG, it is possible to hand tailor your input to exploit the compression algorithm.  Even further down the line are formats like SVG (mentioned in the question), which encode vector graphics rather than a raster image.  SVG golf is extremely non-trivial, you have to work with geometric reasoning and writing an SVG is much more like writing in a programming language than an image.

However there's a big difference between what is possible and what is done.  Just because you can in theory write an interesting PNG answer doesn't mean that every PNG answer is interesting. I certainly agree that just uploading a plain, un-tampered, PNG as your submission is boring.  It doesn't require any effort at all.  It's not clever or fun.

There's not really an easy way to tease apart the interesting answers from the uninteresting ones.  Or the interesting formats from the uninteresting ones.  You say this question is not about SVG, but *why?* it is an image format.  It seems you agree that SVG is more interesting, but who is going to make that call for every format?  We already have an issue with unnecessary meta-cruft and rules.

It's just subjective.

But luckily we have a tool for that! We can vote on answers.  If you think an answer is boring you can downvote it.  If you think it's really interesting or shows high effort you can upvote it.

So I don't think there is any good reason to ban these.  It doesn't actually achieve anything.  Boring answers happen all the time no matter how many rules we have.  But banning them blocks potentially interesting answers.